# "Strong enough" or "enough strong"?

Tags: adverbs

> 1. She is *enough* **strong**.
> 2. She is **strong** *enough*.

Would you explain your explanations in detail? I am confused.

Comment: The second one is grammatical, the first one is not. That is the main difference. _Enough_ modifying _strong_ should follow _strong_. "There are enough apples; the apples are ripe enough to eat."

Comment: @oerkelens Comments are for comments.  Answers are for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adverb *enough* is a **postmodifier**.  Unlike most adverbs, it comes **after** the adjective it modifies.

> *She is enough strong.

This is incorrect.  *Enough* should come after *strong*, not before.

> She is strong enough.

This is correct.  *Enough* comes after *strong*.

Comment: could you also comment on oerkelens' example "There are enough apples"? Is "enough" this example a "noun" as JMB seems to claim in his answer?

Comment: @Nico That *enough* is an adjective, and like most adjectives it can appear attributively ("I have enough apples") or predicatively ("These apples are enough").

Comment: I don't think I fully understand all the uses. "She is enough strong" sounds wrong to me, but I don't see why I can't work as an adjective.

Comment: @Nico Adjectives don't modify other adjectives.  As an adverb, *enough* is a postmodifier.  In "strong enough", *strong* is an adjective, so *enough* must be an adverb and therefore must come after, not before.

Answer (score 3):

You can answer your own question by applying the relevant rule of "enough". Here are two useful rules for "enough":

> **adjective > enough**

Ex: She is wise enough to know when she's making a mistake.

> **enough > noun**

Ex: He had enough strength to be able to climb out of the hole.

Comment: Interesting rule, I hadn't thought of it that way before! You might also explicitly say which of the OP's options is correct, though.

Comment: You're right, I could. I wasn't being short, I just think that knowledge of basic language constructs (nouns, adjectives, verbs etc) is essential when learning a language. I gave enough for OP to make his/her own decision. For future reference, however, the second is correct. "She is strong enough".